# How to Subtract Group total of same field in crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Say I have Fields Like
SNo-----S/F----Amt
1--------S---------100
2--------S---------100
3--------S---------100
4--------S---------100
---------------------**400** -> Group Total 
1--------F---------100
2--------F---------100
3--------F---------100
---------------------**300** -> Group Total 
1--------R---------100
2--------R---------100
---------------------**200** -> Group Total

I want to do like (Grouptotal-S) + (Grouptotal-F) - (Grouptotal-R)
More Like 400 + 300 - 200 = **500** as Grand Total.

I searched the internet and came across `evaluateAfter` but didn't understand how to apply because all the example shows group subtract between 2 different fields and I have a single field here i.e (Amt) in different Groups

Edited : 
To understand more, I am adding some images below.
Image 1:
[image: Crystal Report Designer Image]

Image 2:
[image: Crystal Report Preview Image]

**Note: I solved my problem by using RunningTotal but I have to take 2 running totals for 1 field and I have approx 5 fields to do the same.**

I just want to know if there an easy way just subtract the group total of the same field??

Please rectify me if I am wrong somewhere in the question.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Does the formula not work for this?

Have you tried creating a new formula and you can find your group totals under Report Fields.  Write your formula as needed and then you can place that formula in the report/page footer.

Example

(Group 1 SUM + GROUP 2 SUM) - GROUP 3 SUM

Comment: How? The group total field is same. Like if I Do like -> Right Click on Amt field --> Insert ---> Summary --> Change to Groupwise instead of grand total --> OK. It'll only add 1 field in the group footer. How to show you? Shall I upload a screenshot link here?

Comment: How I get these fields, (Group 1 SUM),(Group 2 SUM) separately

Comment: Please see the question again, I have edited and added images to better understand it.